# computing limit of compositions of functions

Tags: limits, functions

The graph of the function $$f(x)=x+\frac18 \sin2\pi x$$ where $0 \leq x\leq1$ is shown.Let $f_1(x)=f(x),f_{n+1}(x)=f(f_n(x))$,for $n \geq 1$

[image]

I checked the derivative of the function.It is greater than $0$ $\forall$ x in the interval.It implies that function is increasing in nature.Also $f(x)>x \forall x\epsilon(0,0.5)$.Similarly $ f(x) $ is less than $ x $,for the rest of the interval. At $ x=0.5, f(x)=x$.Therefore the composition functions will lie above the actual function for $x\epsilon (0,0.5)$ and below for the rest.Hence all compositions intersect the line y=x at $ x=0.5$ .However I am not sure which option will be correct.Please help me out.Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for showing some effort and getting the ball rolling. This really helps us out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if you are just looking for the answer to the multiple choice or to evaluate each statement. If the former your best bet is to test whether condition (I) is true. If it is false, (which seems likely) then your only choice is B.

If we start down this path:

We ask how many $x \in [0,1]: f(x)=0$?

The answer is just one $x=0$.

We can then ask: What happens to $f(f(x))$ if $x>.5$? if $x<.5$?

If $x\geq.5$ then $f(x)\geq0.5$ thus $f(f(x))\geq0.5$ also $f(x) < x$ thus $f(f(x))\leq f(x)$

If $x\leq.5$ then $f(x)\leq 0.5$ thus $f(f(x)) \leq 0.5$ also $f(x) >x$ thus $f(f(x))\geq f(x)$.

This tells us that if $x!=0$ and $f(x)!=0$ then $f_n (x) !=0$ which tells us that at best there is one solution to $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}f_n(x)=0$. Thus (I) is false.

We can see from our previous statements that as $n$ increases solutions not at $x=0,1$ get closer and closer to 0.5. This seems to imply (II).

We can use the same argument to show that $f(x)!=1$ except at $x=1$. Disproving (III).

Finally from our arguments we know that at worst there are two points that will behave badly $x=0,1$ which is finite so (IV) is false.

Answer (score 1):

First notice that the derivative is $$ f^{\prime}(x)= \frac{\pi \cos\left( 2  \pi   x\right) }{4}+1 $$
It attains maximum values at $x= \{0, 1\}$ which is
$\frac{\pi }{4}+1$. 
Also $f^\prime(x)=1$ for $x=1/4$ and $x=3/4$.
So you can  use the Fixed Point Theorem with a regularization factor of 
$k=\frac{\pi }{4}+1$ and define a new rescaled recursion
$$
g_{n+1}(x) = g( g_{n}(x))/k, \ \ g_1 (x)=f(x)
$$
This has fixed points $0$ and $1$ and so has the original recursion.

So I and III are false.
For $x=1/2$ $f^\prime(x)=1 - \pi /4 < 1$ so the  Fixed Point Theorem can be used without regularization.

So the answer should be II only.

Comment: Bu actually I am not sure if even II is correct. If I plot the recursion about $x=1/2$ it does not seem horizontal enough.

Comment: I can explain the limit for II to be true. You observed that $f(1/2)=1/2$ that means if we ever touch 1/2 in our recursion we'll stay there. The other thing to observe is that if $x>1/2$ then each recursion step is monotonically decreasing. You have a procedure that is monotonically decreasing, bounded below, and has an infimum of 1/2. Thus in the limit that point will approach 1/2 as well as any other number greater than 1/2 but less than 1. You can also prove this on the other side, but one side is sufficient to establish infinitely many solutions.